# Reading frames from multiple threads from video file using cv2.VideoCapture()?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, video-capture

I have an mp4 file and I want to read all of the frames, do some processing on them, then write them back to a file as fast as possible. My code works fine with a few threads, but when I run 10 threads the video jitters like its playing at a fast FPS. What is wrong with my code?

My reading code:

```
    if frame_counter<total_frames-1:
    with lock:
        try:
            success,img = video.read()
        except Exception as e:
            print("EXCEPTION: video.read(): ",e)
            break
    if success:
        img = process_image(img)
        with lock:
            foundIndex = False
            while not foundIndex:
                for i in range(len(threads)):
                    if threads[i]["index"]==frame_counter:
                        foundIndex = True
                        writeframes.append(img)
```

My writing code:

```
    seqclip = moviepy.editor.ImageSequenceClip(writeframes,fps)
    if videoclip.audio:
        seqclip = seqclip.set_audio(audio)
    try:
        seqclip.write_videofile(filename,audio_codec=codec)
    except Exception as e:
        print("EXCEPTION: write_videofile(): ",e)
    seqclip.close()
    videoclip.close()
    del videoclip
    if audio:
        del audio
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and make sure your code is **minimal** and **complete** - see [mcve]. Thank you.